# Is it possible to specify which overloaded function runs in Java

Tags: java, overloading, signature

Given the methods:

```
String[] foo(int i){#doSomething;}

String[] foo(double i){#doesSomethingDifferent;}
```

Is it possible to write `foo(int i){return foo(double d);}`
so that it does not run the recursive `foo(int i){return foo(int i);}` ?

While I understand this would would not be recommended by any means, I am searching to find what mechanisms would allow or disallow it?

Comment: You can try `String[] foo(int i){return foo((double) i);}`

Comment: You can explicitly cast to match the method you want.

Comment: You call the overload you want by specifying the appropriate arguments. If you call `foo` with an `int` parameter, it calls `foo(int)`; if you call it with a `double` parameter, it calls `foo(double)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify implicitly the method that will be called by passing an actual parameter.

```
foo(int i) { return foo(1d); /*it will call foo(double i)*/ }
foo(int i) { return foo(1); /*recursive call*/ }
```

Answer (score 3):

It should happen automatically. The idea behind overloading is that the method signatures should not be exactly the same, particularly the method parameters. When you pass in a `double` value in as a parameter it will call `foo(double d)`. When you pass an `int` in as the parameter it will call `foo(int i)`. To ensure that the `double` method is called you can cast to a `double` using `(double)x`, where `x` is the integer).

Answer (score 3):

You can try `String[] foo(int i){return foo((double) i);}`. This way you are explicitly telling compiler to invoke `foo(double d)` from `foo(int i)`. So no recursive call will be made.

In case of overloading, when a method is called with some parameter, compiler tries to find a method which will be best fit for the passed argument(s). In your case if you simply call `String[] foo(int i){return foo(i);}`, `foo(int i)` version will be invoked, since it's the best fit for the passed argument (of type `int`). That is why to invoke the `double` version of `foo`, you explicitly have to tell compiler that the passed argument is of type `double`.